# How to Generate Category Specific Site Map in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

Can anyone please suggest any extension or custom code that'll help me to generate category specific sitemap?

We have around 500K+ products and would like to generate sitemap like

```
www.website.com/sitemap/category1.xml
www.website.com/sitemap/category2.xml
www.website.com/sitemap/category3.xml
www.website.com/sitemap/category4.xml
```

Comment: Could you do this? I am interested in this functionality

Answer (score 1):

I have created a custom script that'll generate a sitemap for the first level of child categories. Hope it'll help someone.

Download 'SitemapGenerator.php' from https://github.com/icamys/php-sitemap-generator

```
set_time_limit(18000);
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require 'app/bootstrap.php';
require_once 'SitemapGenerator.php';
$params = $_SERVER; 
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params); 
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager(); 
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$productCollection = $obj->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$categoryCollection = $obj->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$sitemap_path = getcwd() .'/sitemaps/';
// Get First Level of Childerns
$categoryIds = Array('3');
foreach ($categoryIds as $categoryId) {

    $_category = $categoryCollection->create();
    $category = $_category->load($categoryId);
    $categories = $category->getCollection()
            ->addIsActiveFilter()
            ->addOrderField('name')
            ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren());
    foreach ($categories as $category) {

        $name = $category->getName();
        $name =  preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', '', strtolower($name));
        $file = $sitemap_path.$name.'.xml';
        if(file_exists($file))
        {
            @unlink($file);
        }
        $categoryProducts = $productCollection->create();
        $categoryProducts->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $categoryProducts->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => [$category->getId()] ]);
        $categoryProducts->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
        $categoryProducts->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
        if(count($categoryProducts))
        {
            $generator = new \Icamys\SitemapGenerator\SitemapGenerator('');
            $generator->createGZipFile = false;
            $generator->maxURLsPerSitemap = 50000;
            $generator->sitemapFileName = $file;
            foreach ($categoryProducts as $product) {
               $generator->addUrl($product->getProductUrl(), new DateTime(), 'weekly', '0.5');
            }

            $generator->createSitemap();
            $generator->writeSitemap();
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can disable magento default sitemap and write custom code like below in which you can load the category collection and then loop it

[How get all subcategories of specific category?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95099/how-get-all-subcategories-of-specific-category)